# How to buy and aplly https certification

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

I have a static IP and a web server in my network. I have made a NAT to forward calls to the IP in the web server (IIS 7.5 on windows 7). But I need to use https. For this reason I have to buy a certification and apply it to web server. I am totally new to certifications. How can I do this. Buying a certification and apply it.

Comment: What kind of network? Internet facing or just an internal network for a company? Besides, such questions are off-topic and should go to Server Fault.

Comment: A company's internal network

Comment: In that situation, talk to your network/domain administrators who can create/manage internal certificate authorities to issue your certificates. You don't have to buy from the outside.

Comment: Sorry... I mean that the web server is in an internal network and with NAT I expose it to Internet through the ISP static IP for which I need to issue a cert.

Comment: Then that question goes off-topic completely. Use a search engine to locate a good certificate authority and they can teach you how to request/install. Or you can use alternatives such as Let's Encrypt or Cloudflare. Has nothing to do with programming here.